# How to boost PHP page?

Tags: php

Basically it takes my PHP code 10 seconds to send the GET request + load,

And in addition there is an active proxy, But the proxy itself is fast.

I'd love to know how to speed up the php code

```
<?php
$u = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$n = str_replace("/num?","","$u");
$lines  = @file("info.txt");
$i=1;
foreach($lines  as $line ){
$var["line" . $i] = $line;
$i++;
}
extract($var);
stream_context_set_default(array('http' => array('proxy' => "$line1", 'request_fulluri' => true, 'header' => "Cookie: PHPSESSID=$line2")));
$url[$n] = "http://**********/$n";
$data[$n] = file_get_contents($url[$n]);
$values[$n] = json_decode($data[$n], true);
$url[$n] = $values[$n]['results']['otherurl'];
header("Location: ".$url[$n]);
?>
```

*After the request is sent, I get a link to a particular broadcast, it just creates a new token on every request

The link of the broadcast itself takes a second to load

What helps me is to work with cron, and send the generated link to service as bit.do,

But if i can speed up the code, it's better

Comment: It is completely unclear what your code does, or why it would take 10 seconds to redirect.

Comment: presumably that is all network activity. If it's a big file or coming off a slow server, 10 seconds isn't surprising.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware After the request is sent, I get a link to a particular broadcast, it just creates a new token on every request. The link of the broadcast itself takes a second to load

Comment: Without actually peppering your code with microtimestamps to find the exact point of slowness (which I'm betting is file_get_contents on a slow URL), its just guesswork.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why would you loop through all lines of info.txt if you only use the first 2?
Why are you making all variables after `stream_context_set_default` an array if everything has the same index or key in the end?

Comment: @rolfv1 I need only the two lines right, someone help me with the loop part, can I shorten the code? I did not understand the second question, I just added a proxy and header, otherwise the broadcast would not work for me

Comment: @IncredibleHat The broadcast itself works only to the ip address through which the request is sent, otherwise I would attach a link. Basically the broadcast server is fast and takes a second to run the broadcast. But through my code it takes 10

Comment: If your code is not broken but you are seeking optimization advice, CodeReview is a good place to park this question.

Comment: My best guess is what @IncredibleHat already mentioned, `file_get_contents` is probably encountering some kind of network latency.  My advice to you would be to use a profiler like xhprof or xdebug to at least confirm what part of the code is slow, and if it is indeed the network, then use something like wireshark to figure out why.

Comment: a 10 seconds dead latency smells like a DNS issue (typically a fallback happens after 5 seconds).